# Mysterious crashes/freezes in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, freeze, logout

I am using 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 for last two years. Machine is slightly older 3 years or so.
No hardware changes to machine - even using same mouse and keyboard. I keep service packs up to date. No untrusted software - may be except Wekbit GTK latest version and its dependencies which I get from official sites and build it myself.

For the last month or so, I am experiencing sudden freezing of UI - almost every day or every other day. Log files (syslog/kern) do nor reveal anything interesting. The machine used to rock solid before this point and rarely needed reboot.

When problem happens, usual place I have seen it happening is in eclipse context menu- after right clicking on something. Don't know if eclipse related or I just notice it because I spend lot of time in eclipse -as its my primary work tool. When this happens GUI does not accept keystrokes. I can move the mouse, but can not click anywhere. I have two monitors and OS somehow forgets to paint another monitor.

However I can still use ctrl-alt F2 etc and from there I can reboot.

Apart from searching causes of this problem, is there any way I can logoff GUI user without rebooting the whole box? I tried restarting lightdm service, keyboard/mouse and monitors started working again, but it created new session with my eclipse and other tools in limbo.

Comment: you can use `kill -9 -1`